# Dapper.net error with SqlMapper.cs

Tags: c#, vb.net, dapper, dapper-extensions

I started a new project using vb.net and micro ORM DAPPER.NET . Over nuGet I integrated the dapper and dapper.simpleCRUD . My problem is appears when i want to execute some CRUD  operations i have a problem with SqlMapper.cs .I do not know whay because I successfully integrated into the project a "dapper.simpleCRUD" extension . What am doing wrong??

[image: ERROR]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I try  manual to add SqlMapper.cs file and i get this:

[image]

Comment: Double click on that selection to check on Object Browser if there is any class named SqlMapper

Comment: No i don't have it? How can i fix this?

Comment: You problem is with this reference, try to extract only the DLL from the Path of this Package and then reference it again.

Comment: Try to insert SqlMapper.cs to your solution using this url: https://kevingessner.kilnhg.com/Code/Public/Attack-of-the-Clones/MvcMiniProfiler/Files/SampleWeb/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs?rev=c3f12fbd0629&nr=

Comment: The "missing sqlmapper.cs" is just the IDE trying to be more specific about the exception. However, the exception should already have enough information without this - I think you're investigating an unrelated issue. What is the actual exception?

Comment: I don't know. When i tray to do this query I have the error that told me the above error Sqlmapper.cs missing . I'm really confused
                                                                                                          **Dim user = konekcija.Query(Of tOpi)("SELECT OPIS FROM tOpis").ToList**

        **DataGridView1.DataSource = user**

Comment: that isn't the exception; that is just the IDE getting in your way. Ignore that, and concentrate on finding the exception - it'll be on one of the windows. Worst case: run it outside of the IDE, so you can see the error without the IDE trying to "help" you. Also, if you reply, include @marc in the comment, then I'll get notified :)

Comment: @MarcGravell oh yes, that is. I had a problem with the syntax of the query. Thank you, sir . Please write this like answer. I need to mark that question as resolved. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The IDE is simply presenting a confusing UI here. The problem  is **not** that `SqlMapper.cs` is missing. Rather, some exception has happened (presumably a SQL error), and rather than simply show you the failure, the IDE is *attempting* to show you the original point where the error is detected *as code*. Which it doesn't have! Basically, **ignore the request for SqlMapper.cs** - that is just the IDE having a bad day. What you *actually* need to do here is to focus on *finding the exception*. That *might* be hidden in another window, or it might appear when you click one of the buttons. In the worst case, just *run the code outside of the IDE* - the IDE can't stick its nose in if it isn't running! You should eventually find the *actual* exception, which is probably either a ADO.NET connection failure, or invalid SQL being used.